# How to change mouse input to key input in Unity 2D (C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Currently have a game where the player moves a Raquet to hit a ball using a mouse. I want to change this to using key input(left and right arrows) along a horizontal axis to make the game accessible. I changed some code so the player can move the racquet in this way however the ball doesn't move on contact and should move farther than it currently does.
I'm trying to change the mouse input in this code to key input (left and right arrows)? How to I create the same executions with both arrows?

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
    {
        Vector2 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);

        if (wasJustClicked)
        {
            wasJustClicked = false;

            if (playerCollider.OverlapPoint(mousePos))
            {
                canMove = true;
            }
            else
            {
                canMove = false;
            }
        }
        if (canMove)
        {
            Vector2 clampedMousePos = new Vector2(
                Mathf.Clamp(mousePos.x, playerBoundary.Left, playerBoundary.Right),
                Mathf.Clamp(mousePos.y, playerBoundary.Down, playerBoundary.Up)
            );
            rb.MovePosition(clampedMousePos);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        wasJustClicked = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void Update()
{
    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(horizontal, vertical);

    rb.MovePosition(movement);
}
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read [answer]. Code-only answers might not be very helpful to OP or future viewers of this answer. Good answers include some explanation of _why_ this answer works and what the OP got wrong.